# Can one delay chalkboard drawings in a Quarto presentation?

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I'm making a Quarto presentation using the chalkboard feature, and in particular making pre-recorded drawings.  The only issue that I'm having is that the drawings come in too quickly.

I cracked open the JSON holding the data for the drawings and found that I can manually bump up the time value and accomplish this effect.  However, with massive data files, actually doing this manually for all the slides throughout the presentation would be impractical.  Is there a way to more programmatically control the animation replay?

I'm developing in VSCode, but if anyone uses RStudio and knows how to do this there, I'd be interested.  If it's effective enough I might just switch over to RStudio.